# Select new Email by Subject and Date Range

Tags: vba, outlook

I developed a macro to save attached files from selected emails with a subject depending on the body.

I would like to make the macro select the emails instead of doing it manually.

Goal: Select emails depending on their subject and an specific date range.

1. Filter mails received in a specified date range which corresponds with subject "Ordenes" and come from "ordenes@ordenes.com". This must be done without reading every single email on the inbox folder as I do not have the option of moving historical ones to another folder (shared email).
2. Select the mails that match the previous step and then call a macro called "SaveAttachements".

I've been checking `Items.Restrict`, `Items.Find`, `Explorer.Selection`, `Explorer.AddToSelection` but I don't seem to be getting the right concept.

Comment: Please the queries you have tried for Find and Restrict. There is no reason to use the Selection object.

Comment: "This must be done without reading every single email on the inbox folder" - as far as i know this will be a problem, a macro can run through all emails and work with the ones meeting your criteria, but it can not "filter" befor going through them.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter (select) emails with `.Restrict`, which allows multiple conditions.

```vb
Option Explicit


Private Sub restrict_SenderEmailAddress_Subject_DateRangeRecent()

Dim itms As Items
Dim resItms As Items
Dim itm As Object

Dim srchSenderEmailAddress As String
Dim srchSubject As String

Dim dateRangeDays As Long
Dim srchDatePeriod As String

Dim strFilterBuild As String
Dim resItmsBuild As Items

Dim strFilter As String

Dim i As Long

Set itms = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

'For i = 1 To itms.Count
'    Debug.Print itms(i).SenderEmailAddress
'Next

srchSenderEmailAddress = "ordenes@ordenes.com"

' If you cannot get the quotes right all at once, build the filter.
strFilterBuild = "[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & srchSenderEmailAddress & "'"
Debug.Print strFilterBuild

Set resItmsBuild = itms.Restrict(strFilterBuild)
If resItmsBuild.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No " & srchSenderEmailAddress & " email."
    'MsgBox "No " & srchSenderEmailAddress & " email."
    Exit Sub
End If

srchSubject = "Ordenes"

strFilterBuild = strFilterBuild & " And [Subject] = '" & srchSubject & "'"
Debug.Print strFilterBuild

Set resItmsBuild = itms.Restrict(strFilterBuild)
If resItmsBuild.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No " & srchSenderEmailAddress & " email with subject " & srchSubject
    'MsgBox "No " & srchSenderEmailAddress & " email with subject " & srchSubject
    Exit Sub
End If

' adjust as needed
dateRangeDays = 1400
srchDatePeriod = Format(Date - dateRangeDays, "yyyy-mm-dd")
'Debug.Print srchDatePeriod

strFilterBuild = strFilterBuild & " And [ReceivedTime] > '" & srchDatePeriod & "'"
Debug.Print strFilterBuild

Set resItmsBuild = itms.Restrict(strFilterBuild)
resItmsBuild.sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

If resItmsBuild.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No " & srchSenderEmailAddress & " email with subject " & srchSubject & " in the last " & dateRangeDays & " days."
    'MsgBox "No " & srchSenderEmailAddress & " email with subject " & srchSubject & " in the last " & datePeriodDays & " days."
    Exit Sub
End If

' This should match the final strFilterBuild to confirm it can be done all at once.
strFilter = "[SenderEmailAddress] = '" & srchSenderEmailAddress & "' And [Subject] = '" & srchSubject & "' And [ReceivedTime] > '" & srchDatePeriod & "'"
Debug.Print strFilter

Set resItms = itms.Restrict(strFilter)
resItms.sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

If resItms.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No " & srchSubject & " email on " & srchDatePeriod
End If

For i = 1 To resItms.Count
    Debug.Print resItms(i).ReceivedTime & ": " & resItms(i).Subject
    'SaveAttachments resItms(i)
Next

End Sub
```